# under lua, how can I if check file attributes only if the LuaFileSystem package is installed

Tags: lua, luafilesystem

I have some code which uses LuaFileSystem. However not all systems it will be run on have LuaFileSystem installed. I would like to check if it is installed, and only run the code if it is. Something like this (but this fails and states lfs is a null value)

```
local lfsExists, lfs = pcall(function () require "lfs" end)
if lfsExists then
    local lastUpdateTime = lfs.attributes( mapFilePName ).modification
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That pcall-ed function doesn't return any values. Drop `, lfs`.

Also you don't need the anonymous function.

```
local lfsExists = pcall(require, "lfs")
```

Or to use the return value from `require` instead of the (implicit) global.

```
local lfsExists, lfs = pcall(require, "lfs")
```

Comment: ... or add `return` before the `require`. Your solution without the anonymous function already returns the `lfs` module table as the second value, btw.

Comment: Yes, I chose not to fix the unnecessary function case. The point about the return from directly calling `require` is a good one though.